# How can a seed job specify its own lookupStrategy?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

Using the Job DSL plugin, I'm trying to make the seed job generate new jobs in a Jenkins folder relative to the location of the seed job.  So if the seed job is in the `/my-project` folder, and it creates `my-job`, I'd like `my-job` to also be created in `/my-project`.

The goal is to do this *without* requiring the person setting up the seed job to remember to manually set the context in the build step. Instead, the script for the seed job itself should specify the location.

**Approach 1**

Writing the seed job like this:

```
job("my-job") {
}
```

creates `my job` in the root of the Jenkins project. That's not at all what I wanted.

**Approach 2**

Modifying the seed job to include a path

```
job("/my-project/my-job") {
}
```

creates `my job` in the desired folder, but it's not reusable. If someone wants to create a second instance of `my job` in a different folder, they have to edit the seed job's script file first.

**Approach 3**

The [lookupStrategy method](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/job-steps-dsl-lookupStrategy) looks promising, but only seems to be useful if the seed job creates another seed job.  So, if I modify the seed job to look like this:

```
job("my-job") {
    steps {
        dsl {
            text("job('sub-job')")
            lookupStrategy('SEED_JOB')
        }
    }
}
```

Then `my-job` is still created in the root folder, but `sub-job` at least will be created relative to `my-job`.

**Approach 4**

The JOB_NAME environment variable contains the folder path. It is possible to get the desired effect by doing some string manipulation and then using the approach from Attempt 2, but that seems a bit inelegant.

Is there some mechanism already baked in which allows for setting the `lookupStrategy` for the job currently executing?

Comment: Are you hard coding the folder names inside the job dsl script??

Comment: Yes. That was my initial workaround to the default JENKINS_ROOT behavior. Since there doesn't seem to be a way for a seed job to specify its own lookupStrategy, I've settled for parsing the `JOB_NAME` environment variable to set an absolute path.